# Centering text in SVG path

Tags: svg

I am trying to center horizontally and vertically `text` in `path` with the 
`startOffset` and `text-anchor` attributes, but centering doesn't work.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<svg id="line-vis" width="640" height="300" viewBox="0 0 640 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="cursor: pointer; overflow: visible; position: relative;">
   <g>
      <g class="line" pointer-events="none" transform="translate(365.1979064941406,134.5977783203125)">
         <path id="tooltip-line-vis" d="M120 60 L120 0 L0 0 L0 60 L54 60 L60 66 66 60" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#D2DBE9" transform="translate(-60,-75)" style="opacity: 1;"></path>
         <text text-anchor="middle" style="opacity: 1;">
            <textPath class="yLabelVal" xlink:href="#tooltip-line-vis" startOffset="50%" style="opacity: 1;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 500;line-height: 20px;fill: rgb(8, 40, 101);">$5,104.90</textPath>
         </text>
      </g>
      <rect width="640" height="300" fill="none" pointer-events="all"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get what you need I've changed the points of the path. Now the path begins at 0,0. Also I've removed all the transforms. If you need your path in a different position you may use transforms on `#tooltip` as I did in my code.

Please note the attribute dy="35" for the text. This is moving your text upward & in the center.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<svg id="line-vis" width="640" height="300" viewBox="0 0 640 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="cursor: pointer; overflow: visible; position: relative;">
   <g id="tooltip" transform="translate(50,10)">
      <g class="line" pointer-events="none" >
         <!--<path id="tooltip-line-vis" d="M0,60 L54,60 60,66 66,60 120,60 120,0 0,0 0,60"  stroke="#D2DBE9" style="opacity: 1;"></path>-->
        
        <path id="tooltip-line-vis" d="M0,0 L120,0 120,60 66,60 60,66 54,60 0,60 0,0"  stroke="#D2DBE9" style="opacity: 1;"></path>

         <text text-anchor="middle" style="opacity: 1;" fill="gold" dy="35">
            <textPath class="yLabelVal" xlink:href="#tooltip-line-vis" startOffset="60" >$5,104.90</textPath>
         </text>
      </g>
      <rect width="640" height="300" fill="none" pointer-events="all"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```