# svg curve text change

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a SVG file which is showing me text in a curve. I want to change it in PHP.
I am using to get and change a svg library

```
use SVG\SVG;
$svg = SVG::fromFile('testing.svg');
$image = SVG::fromString($svg);
$doc = $image->getDocument();
```

The output of the SVG is

[image: Output]

This is showing me the curved text

When i look at the SVG file it is shows me this code.

```
<rect x="216" y="392.856" style="fill:none;" width="40" height="220"/>
<g>
<g>
    <path d="M219.283,204.885c2.175,2.252,3.263,3.378,5.438,5.63c4.924-4.76,7.447-7.044,12.595-11.421
        c-2.025-2.388-3.039-3.582-5.064-5.969c1.431-1.216,2.15-1.817,3.597-3.005c4.742,5.79,7.113,8.684,11.854,14.474
        c-1.347,1.106-2.017,1.666-3.349,2.799c-2.27-2.676-3.404-4.012-5.674-6.688c-5.107,4.342-7.609,6.607-12.495,11.329
        c2.438,2.523,3.656,3.785,6.093,6.309c-1.26,1.218-1.886,1.833-3.129,3.076c-5.291-5.291-7.937-7.937-13.229-13.228
        C217.257,206.854,217.93,206.193,219.283,204.885z"/>
    <path d="M251.546,193.57c2.073,2.574,5.886,1.379,9.419-1.125c2.529-1.793,3.9-3.086,5.031-4.313
        c0.634,0.417,0.952,0.625,1.583,1.045c-1.043,1.163-2.937,2.965-6.002,5.148c-5.93,4.225-11.025,4.852-13.523,1.66
        c-2.498-3.191-0.975-8.523,4.942-12.758c6.63-4.745,10.599-2.599,11.956-0.534c0.274,0.417,0.403,0.798,0.499,1.034
        C259.79,187.46,257.006,189.428,251.546,193.57z M261.067,184.561c-0.833-1.313-3.225-2.661-7.349,0.299
        c-3.707,2.661-3.926,5.719-3.188,7.284C254.687,188.993,256.795,187.477,261.067,184.561z"/>
```

In each path tag,there is one letter of my curve text. I want to change a single single letter dynamically via jQuery or PHP.

How can I change one letter via jQuery or PHP?

Comment: please show us your best attempt (code) and clarify what it is that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I have upload my question again. please check now

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is pretty difficult to achieve right off the bat.

The SVG data you are using is rendered text. All the points needed to render a letter is right in there, along with the calculated curvature that letter needs at what point of the curve. As you can see on the H, the both legs are not parallel together. 
In the paths to draw them it's also hard coded where to draw them. Moving them is a nightmare.

Since you wish to draw text along a curve, I propose a different solution, that makes it so much easier to manipulate the text data you're displaying.

We're still going to use SVG, but we won't use hard coded "paths of points" to render the text. For more information, read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
  
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
  text-align: center;
}



Resources
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500" >
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Hello How are you
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
```

If you implement that and substitute your own text you'll notice it's offcenter.

For that we can fiddle around with the [startOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678634/1356107) attribute.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
  
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
  text-align: center;
}



Resources
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500" >
      <textPath class="curved-text" xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="60">
        Hello How are you
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
```

And then by adding a class to our text container, we can use a simple jQuery snippet to change the text within the curve to what we want it to be.

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
   $('.curved-text').text("I'm fine thank you");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
  
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
  text-align: center;
}



Resources
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500" >
      <textPath class="curved-text" xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="60">
        Hello How are you
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand your answer, But the svg is created by illustrator, means first i am createing design in illustrator and then exporting it in .svg format to make it dynamic. So whole SVG code is created by illustrator and there are multiple design.

Comment: Any other way which will work with illustrator .svg file?

Comment: Do all the transformation maths in javascript to move one point to the side accounting for the curvature. Your best and most flexible bet is to make all the background and doodads in illustrator of the svg, but keep the text as a textpath. That way you can still use fancy svg display of features, but keep the text flexible. With the text you have, you have no baseline. You could start with straight indesign text and apply mathematical transformations yourself, that way you can move text as you wish with a lot of math. But if yous start with curved text it's much much harder to get it good.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I like your solution also. Let me try to do with math calculations.Thanks Again.